# xpath to dic python, lxml and xml

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Is there a quick way by using xpath from lxml in Python to convert following xml to dictionary? Or any other efficient way?

```
<rec item="1">
    <tag name="atr1">random text</tag>
    <tag name="atr2">random text</tag>
    ..................................        
</rec>
<rec item="2">
    <tag name="atr1">random text2</tag>
    <tag name="atr2">random text2</tag>
    ..................................        
</rec>
<rec item="3">
    <tag name="atr1">random text3</tag>
    <tag name="atr2">random text3</tag>
    ..................................        
</rec>
```

need dictionary like this, or other simillar:

```
dic = [
    {    
        'attr1':'random text',
        'attr2':'random text'
    },
    {    
        'attr1':'random text2',
        'attr2':'random text2'
    },
    {    
        'attr1':'random text3',
        'attr2':'random text3'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension together with a dictionary comprehension:

```
[{ tag.xpath('string(@name)') : tag.xpath('string()') for tag in record.xpath('tag')} for record in records.xpath('//rec')]
```

Here is a complete example:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
xml = '''<records>
<rec item="1">
    <tag name="atr1">random text</tag>
    <tag name="atr2">random text</tag>
    ..................................        
</rec>
<rec item="2">
    <tag name="atr1">random text2</tag>
    <tag name="atr2">random text2</tag>
    ..................................        
</rec>
<rec item="3">
    <tag name="atr1">random text3</tag>
    <tag name="atr2">random text3</tag>
    ..................................        
</rec>
</records>'''
records = ET.fromstring(xml)
rec_list = [{ tag.xpath('string(@name)') : tag.xpath('string()') for tag in rec.xpath('tag') } for rec in records.xpath('rec')]
print(rec_list)
```

Outputs

```
[{'atr1': 'random text', 'atr2': 'random text'}, {'atr1': 'random text2', 'atr2': 'random text2'}, {'atr1': 'random text3', 'atr2': 'random text3'}]
```

Comment: It works! Now I am looking how to improve the Output. As I know in advance the names of the attributes (name="attr1) perhaps more efficient way would be to have following structure:

Comment: attribute_name = {'atr1', 'atr2'}
    attribute_values = [ {'random text','random text'}, {'random text2','random   text2'}, {'random text3','random text3'}]

but not sure it will bring any value?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

```
source = lxml.etree.fromstring('xml_source_is_here')
[{attr:text} for attr,text in zip(source.xpath('//tag/@name'), source.xpath('//tag/text()'))]
```

Output:

```
[{'atr1': 'random text'}, {'atr2': 'random text'}, 
{'atr1': 'random text2'}, {'atr2': 'random text2'}, 
{'atr1': 'random text3'}, {'atr2': 'random text3'}]
```